# AppLoader Issue with plist xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, info.plist

I have been fighting with this issue when trying to use AppLoader for my Xamarin.iOS app which has a Share extension also.

When I load the solution in AppLoader, it returns the following error

```
ERROR ITMS-90362: 
"Invalid Info.plist value. 
The value for the key 'NSExtensionActivationRule' in bundle MyApp.app/PlugIns/Share.appex is invalid.

Please refer to the App Extension Programming Guide on https://developer.apple.com"
```

**This is my extension's `plist`**

[image: plist for share extension]

Looking at the `NSExtensionActivationRule`, I am unable to see any issues unless I am doing something else incorrect.

Just in case if you want to compare extension `plist` with container app's `plist` -

**This is my container app's `plist`**

[image: container app's plist]

**P.S.** In debug mode I fully tested the app and it works fines in Simulator but AppLoader just doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I found the issue. I did the following

1. Removed `TRUEPREDICTAE` key in the extension `plist`
2. Matched the extension **build version** to the container build version by changing it from `1` to `1.0` (yah, it has to be exact)

Hope this helps someone else